# can't center and align label with textbox in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a website with my friend. Currently we are creating a Contact page, but i'm stuck aligning the labels with the input boxes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmqTQ.jpg

my ASP.net code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <title>Contact</title>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent" runat="server">
    <div style="background-color: white; height: 750px;" class="container" id="contact-page">

        <label for="InputFullName">Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputFullName" placeholder="Full Name"/>


        <label for="InputEmail">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmai" placeholder="Example@example.com"/>


        <label for="InputSubject">Subject</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputSubject" placeholder="Subject"/>


        <label for="InputDescription">Description</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="InputDescription" placeholder="Description"/>

        <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

my CSS file that is linked to that page:

```
/* Contact Page start */

#contact-page input {
    display: block;
    width: 450px;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: white;
}

#contact-page .btn btn-default {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#contact-page #InputDescription {
    height:250px
}

#contact-page label {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}

/* Contact Page end */
```

I'm using bootstrap 3.

Comment: Add line-height into the label some as height of input box

Comment: How does it appear to you? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/84e8ef9bcd416ac4fdccf5c4d741cf59 this is how i see it atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be possible for you to use a textform instead ?

```
           <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30">
           Description
           </textarea>
```